# TensorFlow New Op: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'custom_op'

Tags: tensorflow

I am creating new ops (https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) for TensorFlow (r1.0) running both on x86 and ARMv7.

Minor code modifications are necessary to run TensorFlow on ARMv7, but this guide helps a lot:
https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md.

But I noticed that the **custom operations do not work on my ARMv7 installation** of TensorFlow.

For example, when I test my custom operation in a Python script on ARMv7:

```
import tensorflow as tf
_custom_op_module = tf.load_op_library('custom_op.so')
custom_op = _custom_op_module.add_stub
```

I get the following error (that does not show up on x86):

```
$ python test_custom_op.py 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom_op.py", line 3, in <module>
    add_stub = _custom_op_module.add_stub
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'custom_op'
```

I further investigated the issue, and apparently there is not my custom operation in the .so library file.

```
$ python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> _custom_op_module = tf.load_op_library('custom_op.so')
>>> dir(_custom_op_module)
>>> ['LIB_HANDLE', 'OP_LIST', '_InitOpDefLibrary', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', '_collections', '_common_shapes', '_op_def_lib', '_op_def_library', '_op_def_pb2', '_op_def_registry', '_ops', '_text_format']
>>> _custom_op_module.OP_LIST

>>>
```

The same commands on x86 have the following output:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> _custom_op_module = tf.load_op_library('custom_op.so')
>>> dir(_custom_op_module)
>>> ['LIB_HANDLE', 'OP_LIST', '_InitOpDefLibrary', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', '_add_stub_outputs', '_collections', '_common_shapes', '_op_def_lib', '_op_def_library', '_op_def_pb2', '_op_def_registry', '_ops', '_text_format', 'custom_op']
>>> _custom_op_module.OP_LIST
op {
  name: "CustomOp"
  ...
}
>>>
```

Does anybody have similar issue? Can we consider this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar issue with a similar error message when I tried to load my new op, however, my problem was I tried to register a customized op that had the same op name as tensorflow, and that led to a name collision. Changing the name fixed it without recompiling TF.

The error message I encountered:
`AttributeError: module '6e237d88703da016805889179d3f5baa' has no attribute 'custom_op'`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, recompiling and re-installing the TF made it works.